# javascript sort text in CSV

Tags: javascript, replace

I have data in Excel CSV file. This is the format.

```
"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
and the rest
"
```

How can I format this text so that last column has " on the end and make it like this.

```
"","","","","the useful data"
"","","","","the useful data"
"","","","","the useful data"
"","","","","the useful data and the rest"
```

I am using JavaScript for this.

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: Perhaps `text.replace(/\n\"/g,"\"\n")`

Comment: @gurvinder372 — Of what? And even if they could, it would be better to put the code [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) than on a third party site.

Comment: Almost there. There are line that HAVE NO delimiter "," but only text ABCD)" . How to I handle those cases?

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, but I disagree. I know that SO has the built-in feature of adding stack-snippets, but it is simply not as good as jsFiddle ;(.

Comment: Good enough for this code

Answer (score 1):

```
var myCSVContent = ... // your csv here
myCSVContent
    // removes line breaks within value and add whitespace
    .replace(/((?:\\")|[^"])\n([^"])/g, "$1 $2")   
    // removes unwanted line breaks
    .replace(/\n(["\w])([^"]|$)/g, "$1$2")
```

Comment: Almost - the last line becomes `"","","","","the useful dataand the rest"`

Comment: ok, fixed. 
sorry, i can`t come up with more elegant solution, but this will work in most cases, i hope :) even with ```"","","","","the useful data\"
 and the rest"```

Answer (score 0):

It can likely be done in one line, but here you have more control

```js
var text = document.getElementById("x").value;
text = text.replace(/\n/g," ") // change all newlines to one space
           .replace(/"","","",""/g,'\n"","","",""') // reformat on leading string
           .substring(1) // get rid of the leading newline
           .replace(/ "/g,"\""); // get rid of trailing space
document.getElementById("x").value=text
```

```html
<textarea rows=10 cols=50 id="x">"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
and the rest
"</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title suggests you want to sort but you say nothing about how you want it sorted.  Below works for combining the lines.  It simply takes any line without a delimiter and adds it to the previous line.  If the line doesn't start with a space it adds one.

```js
var csvData = `"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
"
"","","","","the useful data
and the rest
"`

function formatCSV(data) {
  var arr = data.split('\n');
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i].split(",").length == 1) {
      if(arr[i] != '"' && arr[i][0] != " ")
        arr[i] = " " + arr[i];
      output[output.length - 1] += arr[i];
      continue;
    }
    output.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return output.join("\n");
}

document.write("<pre>" + formatCSV(csvData) + "</pre>");
```